# Redirecting wordpress to HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, https

I have a .htaccess file generated by a plugin.
It looks like this:

```
# BEGIN Far Future Expiration Plugin
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 168 hours"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Far Future Expiration Plugin

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I need to implement a HTTPS redirection. I've tried adding the following to the file but it gives me a **Too many redirects** error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any tips?

Comment: You only need to check for HTTPS, you don't need to check if your domain has www or not. Either way it will redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This code will redirect any non `https` request to the same page/domain with `https`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Note: some but not all `ssl` certificates don't include the `www` or non www domain depending on how you purchased it.  Due to this you may get an error and in addition to the code above you can use what you were attempting above.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This example will redirect non `www` sites to `www`, switch it around if you need the other case.

Comment: @EricMitjans - you replace yours, and place this at the TOP of your htaccess file (before the WordPress rewrite bits)